# Typescript function declaration separate from implementation

Tags: typescript

I'd like to write a specification for a set of Typescript functions with the implementations in a separate file, and then have tsc check that the actual implementations match the specification.

Something like this:

f-spec.ts:

```js
export declare function foo(s: string, i: int): int;
```

and then in another source file:

f.ts:

```js
// import { foo } from './f-spec' <<< Doesn't work, gives error
export foo(s: string, i: int) { return i }
```

When I actually try to include that import, I get an error "Import declaration conflicts with local definition".

How should I declare the function in one file and implement it in a separate file? (Yes, I'm an old C++ guy and thinking about this as if it were a C++ header file, I know. But this is how I need it in this case.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't support forward function declarations like this.  In the future it [might support forward type/interface declarations](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31894), but I don't know if that would help your use case (and it's not available in TS as of TS3.5 anyway)

---

Workaround: instead of trying to `declare` your function, maybe give it a type:

```
type FooFuncType = (s: string, i: number) => number; // int ain't a thing in JS/TS
```

And then later when you implement your function

```
function foo(s: string, i: number) {
  return s.length + i;
}
```

You can create either a value or type artifact that only compiles cleanly if `foo` conforms to `FooFuncType`:

```
const fooIsRightType: FooFuncType = foo; // okay
// or
type FooIsRightType<T extends FooFuncType = typeof foo> = true; // okay
```

If you do something that doesn't match, like

```
function foo(s: string, i: number) {
  return s + i;
}
```

You get errors:

```
const fooIsRightType: FooFuncType = foo; // error
//    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- string is not assignable to number
// or
type FooIsRightType<T extends FooFuncType = typeof foo> = true; // error
//   -------------------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~
// (s: string, i: number)=>string does not satisdy FooFuncType
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5A1iAnkg3gKCSQBdMZkAxAe0vIFdh4AVU5AXiQAooAuJKIgE4BLYAHMANEiG9gtMACMIAgJRJWAPiSyFSgNxIA9AanAiSECIDkZkMQAWI0SaQApAMoHGbvASQAzengiIUpgf2ouXn5hMUlpLTlFFVxfQgEIIloBMKgAOgAbCDEiOyQAaildXwBfX3hQ-nDKAEkoACUhUTsiZjJeKhpA3rYm-SMkSgxMX3HKAV8SMiQB1o6unpYAHkYkCAAPIiKAEyhl6joGYbViFko-Js12QVoIMeNJrDxavFBIWARkAAhEBHFKERYUc5DFjXSJ8QSOOIyRJKVQaBI6ARvEw2Kw2eyOZzuTzeXwBBjBUJNOHRRFSZGY1T4QhpDJZHLlSo1OoNMx+airTrdYb9KGXGHsfmUbFKARzGbGFkAPxVqrVaqQmwAtFr4TEnEJTsBKDYoFBOqB5IViJQMUkFRN5uCYSt2kKNmRtrsDsdTgMLkwJTcyHcHtdnq9DMZZfLCONCDrE0nkynU2mdZp1eqHTSEbF6XbURpaWIkEdKNAtCa+CBglAjth-dCyF88EA)

Answer (score 1):

In typescript definitions and implementations are in the same namespace.

If you want to have a type, and an implementation that fulfills that type, they must have different names.

However, when you import a type, you can give it an alias allowing you to use the same name in 2 different files.

I would question the sanity of doing this for every function you write though. Even if it's a habit, it tends to be a good idea to try to mimic what developers in a new ecosystem do, before introducing your own variations to it. Master the rules before you break them.

Comment: Yeah, I get that it's a weird case. I don't intend to do it often. I have a particular use case in mind for this though. Given that, how can I import my type with its alias and make sure my implementation conforms to that type?

Comment: `import { a as alias }` is the main syntax. To define a function that uses a specific namespace, use `const functionName: functionType = () => { .. implementation .. };`